# how to scramble a picture using pixels

Tags: java, image

I'm new to coding and currently learning java. I'm currently doing this extra credit assignment that divides a 900x900 picture into 3x3 chunks then scramble it into random positions.

So far, I was able to divide them into 3x3 chunks. However, I'm not sure how to use the pixels that i got and make them into a object. So later it can be called easily and use it to scramble into different positions.

so it would look something like this but the chunks are scrambled
[dividedPicture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sn64T.png)

So, is it possible to get some hints or ideas? Thanks and appreciate the help.

This is the code I got so far

```
  public void extracredit(Picture originPic) {

    Picture [] picture = new Picture[9];
    boolean [] checkFilled = new boolean[9];
    int w = originPic.getWidth();
    int h = originPic.getHeight();
    Pixel pixels;
    for ( int i = 0; i < picture.length; i++) {
      int xIndex = i % 3;

      for ( int x = w/3 * xIndex; x < w/3 * (xIndex + 1); x++) {

        for ( int y = h/3 * xIndex; y < h/3 * (xIndex + 1); y++) {   
          pixels = origin.getPixel(x,y);

        }
      }
    }


  }
```

Comment: Picture?? wher did you get that from??

Comment: You could always put them into a `Collection` and `shuffle` it

Comment: i'm writing this method in a class called Picture which extends to a library call simplePicture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your source pixel matrix.  Create a target pixel matrix of the same pixel rectangular dimensions.  Keep a linked list of what 3x3 target pixel groups remain to be assigned.  Iterating through each 3x3 source pixel group, generate a random integer >= 0 and < the length of the linked list to pick the next 3x3 target pixel group, copy to it, and delete the corresponding entry from the linked list until it is empty.

Comment: Thx for the advice but i figured it out. i made a collection for the chunks of pixels i wanted and use the fisher method to randomized it. thank you to MadProgammer too